# Swift collection view cell greater than collection view frame

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

[image]I have a collectionview that can scroll horizontally. The problem I have is this (can't upload screenshot so I did an illustration):

Green is my collectionView background, pink is my collectionview cells background.

I have like 10 cells, the last cell's content view always exceeds my collection view trailing anchor constraints for some reason.

I created my own flow layout class, I set the itemSize and estimatedItemSize like this:

```
self.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
self.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 32, height: 36)
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this if I turn off "Clip to Bounds", so my recommendation would be to use `collectionView.clipsToBounds = true`, or make sure the "Clip to Bounds" box is checked in your xib/storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

The function to use is :

```
collectionView.clipsToBounds = true.
```

or you can also check on the checkbox in the storyboard.